# How to change the php server time zone?

Tags: php, timezone

We can use any simple code to display the system time only but I need some code to find the server(PHP) time zone and how to change the server time zone?

Comment: Since all the answers are about [date_default_timezone_set](http://no1.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php), there's also [setlocale()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php), which will get the locale if you pass zero as the last parameter. It's all in the PHP manual however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

**Change the value of America/Los_Angeles');**

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the top of a PHP file, or to the top of an included file (if you can't get at the PHP.ini)...

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

From [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Answer (score 0):

Here is function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Here are timezones: http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

And this is how you use it:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Vilnius');
```

Answer (score 0):

For server: In the `php.ini` change the `date.timezone` variable

For script: Refer to the API: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: why NOTHING change with this code:`echo time().'<br />';
ini_set('date.timezone', 'Asia/Calcutta');
echo time().'<br />';
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo time().'<br />';
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
echo time().'<br />';` ???

Answer (score 0):

Use function [date_default_timezone_set()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) in your PHP file.