# About php code and retuning time

Tags: php

Why my php time is 4 hours slower than my pc? How can i fix this?

```
<?php
echo"<H2>it's my test program.</H2>I'll make it my own...<br>";
$string="Tell me the time.";
echo"$string <br>"; 
$string1="It's";
$t=date("H.i"); 
if($t<"18" and $t>"1"){
echo"$string1 evening and its $t.";
}
else{
echo"$string1 $t";
}
?>
```

and it was showing in mozila:

> it's my test program. I'll make it my own... Tell me the time. It's
>   20.36 . But my laptop time is 2.36 am

Comment: Set the correct time-zone in your php file: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: time zones, probably. especially if you're running this via a webserver on some machine OTHER than your laptop.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13229564/how-to-change-the-php-server-time-zone

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you're in the wrong timezone. Right now, Eastern time in the US is 4 hours different from Greenwich Mean Time. You can find out your timezone [with this function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php), and set it [with this one](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).

You can also set it in the php.ini:

```
date.timezone = "America/New_York"
```

[For reference, here are a list of valid timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php).

Comment: But where should I add? I have added my zone to the php.ini file. Now what to do...?